# how to call to method A of class A from method B of class A

Tags: python, class, methods

there seems to be a lot of answers on how to call  method A of class A from class B but none on how to call to method A of class A from method B of class A. this probably easy but am new to oop in python. here is a quick illustration of what am trying to do

```
  class A:
      def __init__():

      def method_A(self):
          xxxxxx
          return xxx...
      def method_B(self):
          ans = method_A(self)
          return ans
```

am getting the following error ======> "global name method_A ' is not defined"

Answer (score 5):

```
ans = self.method_A()
```

`self` is an instance of `A`, and methods on instances are called using `instance.method()`.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes need to be referenced off the object.

```
ans = self.method_A()
```

Comment: class A: def __init__(): def method_A(self, anoder): xxxxxx return xxx... def method_B(self): ans = method_A(anoder,self) return ans

Comment: self.method_A(anoder) takes self to be the first argument which is not what i need... thanks

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a method.

Comment: @trey: Just guessing, but maybe you are looking for `anoder.method_A(self)`?

Comment: @trey: You haven't defined method_A as taking any arguments, just the instance it is called on. You need to define method_A with `def: method_A(self, something):` and call it as `self.method_A(anoder)`.

Comment: @Sven: i tried that but it gave an error. ==> str object no attribute method_A

Comment: @trey: My guess was that `anoder` also is an instance of `A`, but obviously it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

Members of a class are accessed as attributes of `self`, so you just use this:

```
self.method_A()
```

Also, you do not need to pass `self` as parameter explicitly, that is done implicitly. This is all covered in the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), which everyone should read.

Comment: class A:
      def __init__():

      def method_A(self, anoder):
          xxxxxx
          return xxx...
      def method_B(self):
          ans = method_A(anoder,self)
          return ans

Comment: self.method_A(anoder) takes self to be the first argument which is not what i need... thanks

Comment: @trey: `self` always has to be the first argument of a member-function. You cannot change this. Also, don't post code in comments, it looks ugly.

Comment: @ben: soz about that but this is not my actual code...just a similar syntax.